# My Realtek 8125 Ethernet card isn't reconized anymore after an apt-get update/dist-upgrade bring Debian 10 from 4.19.0.16 to 4.19.0.17 Linux image

Tags: debian, ethernet

My computer is under *Debian 10* with this *Linux* image :

```bsh
uname -r
4.19.0-16-amd64
```

and a *R8125* Ethernet card.

```bsh
lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8125 (rev 05)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
```

Today, a new Linux image, `4.19.0.17-amd64` appeared through `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.
These done and the computer rebooted, it doesn't recognize the Ethernet card anymore, and an `ifconfig` respond : *no peripheral found*.
So, of course, I'm using the `4.19.0.16` boot to write this question...

Once, the reseller of my computer moaned about the installation he has had to do with a

```bsh
make install
```

done from a driver directory, `/opt/r8125` it appears he has downloaded from https://github.com/tmacro/r8125.

But I didn't really understood what he did.
I've attempted to use his trick, two months ago, on another *Debian* partition my computer have (with an image `4.19.0-16-amd64`), but :

1. it seems it didn't worked,

```bsh
ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2511888 avril 24 13:43 r8125.ko
```

```
samedi 24 avril 2021, 13:43:55 (UTC+0200)
make -C src/ clean
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /opt/r8125/src »
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build M=/opt/r8125/src clean
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 »
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 »
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /opt/r8125/src »
make -C src/ modules
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /opt/r8125/src »
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build M=/opt/r8125/src modules
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 »
  CC [M]  /opt/r8125/src/r8125_n.o
  CC [M]  /opt/r8125/src/rtl_eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /opt/r8125/src/rtltool.o
  LD [M]  /opt/r8125/src/r8125.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /opt/r8125/src/r8125.mod.o
  LD [M]  /opt/r8125/src/r8125.ko
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 »
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /opt/r8125/src »
make -C src/ install
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /opt/r8125/src »
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build M=/opt/r8125/src INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek modules_install
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 »
  INSTALL /opt/r8125/src/r8125.ko
  DEPMOD  4.19.0-16-amd64
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 »
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /opt/r8125/src »
```

2. or I haven't done something else that was necessary.

It looks strange to me that the network driver isn't able to follow *Linux* upgrades, and it's boring, but I have to comply with this event.

I don't want to upgrade my *Linux* image up to a `5.10` image, but to stay using the current one *Debian 10* suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the story : you only have to post/edit your question, and a few minutes later, it works...

So I wrote here the only things I did but (this time) worked, to help who would stumble upon the same problem I've encountered:

1. Go on the session where Ethernet connection is still available and
   download the *Git* project https://github.com/tmacro/r8125 (for me, reseller put it in `/opt`), or put its content on an USB key.
2. Boot on the no-working session (here the `4.19.0.17-amd64` for me) and execute:

```bsh
cd /opt/r8125/
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

The image `4.19.0.17-amd64` is updated and network works immediately.

(epilogue: I think I was misled by my reseller who told me to do a `make install` from `/opt/r8125` directory when it was a `./autorun.sh` that had to be done? Maybe...)

Answer (score 2):

The RTL8125B support came with kernel 5.9. Debian 10 is using 4.19 in the stable channel.

You can update your kernel to 5.10 from debian-backports if that's ok for you like described e.g. [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/linux-kernel-5-8-and-5-9-debian-10/).

This is a very common problem with current distributions and this controller. The controller is used by many manufacturers on current boards with AMD-Sockets.

I hope that helps, I had to buy a USB-Ethernet-Adapter because when I bougth my board, 5.9 was not yet released by mainline :/

EDIT: To install the new kernel without Internet, you can download the following packages, transfer them via a usb-stick and install them with the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb && apt install -f` and reboot. You should now be able to configure your network.

- [linux-image-amd64](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/linux-image-amd64) ([download](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/amd64/linux-image-amd64/download))
- [linux-image-5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/linux-image-5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64) ([download](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/amd64/linux-image-5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64/download)) (If this version is not available anymore in some future, this package is linked as a dependency from the meta-package above)

Another (maybe easier) way is to connect your mobile via usb and tether its WiFi/LTE-Connection for the kernel-update.

Comment: How is it? Could you update? :)

Comment: I've found currently no way to repair this defective legacy installation, and plan to leave it alone... But I didn't seen your update then. I will think about it.